# Get columns header in Powershell from proc if returns 0 result

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to get columns name in csv file from Powershell.

Powershell has calling SQL procedure and if procedure returns 0 rows then powershell script not even write columns name into csv file.

My code is given below.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString =  "Server=localhost;Database=LIQ_TradeBustTethysTrader5895;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "Execute dbo.Tethys_ArrowGrass_Price_report @loginID = 'ALL', @tableName = 'order_msgs', @firmname = 'ALL', @AssetClass = 'ALL',@OutputBustRecords=0, @ManualOrder=0, @TimeFrom='0:0', @TimeTo='23:59', @ExcludeSimulatedTrades=0, @SingleTable =1"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0] |out-null
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -path "E:\Users\neerajd\Documents\tethystrader-public-dev-general\src\SQL\Misc\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does it return 0 rows or does it return *nothing*? There's a difference. What does the result look like when executed in Management Studio -- do you see column headers?

Comment: When I ran it from Management studio proc gives Columns Header.At the same time powershell shows only `0` in cmd window.

Comment: Start debugging by simplifying. Instead of running a sproc, do a `select foo from bar where...` and check if it returns what's needed. If that works, then the problem is with the sproc. If it doesn't, the problem is on something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE after OPs comment, where they want to export the header only to the csv, if the resultset is empty.

```
if (-not $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]) {
  ($DataSet.Tables[0].Columns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ColumnName) -join ',' |
    Set-Content -Path "E:\Users\neerajd\Documents\tethystrader-public-dev-general\src\SQL\Misc\out.csv"
}
```

ORIGINAL POST

Nothing is returned because the `DataTable` is empty. The schema information is returned, though. Assuming you only have one table in your returned `DataSet', the PowerShell command below will show the columns returned within the metadata.

```
$DataSet.Tables[0].Columns | Out-GridView
```

...or if you want a simple csv list of columns...

```
($DataSet.Tables[0].Columns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ColumnName) -join ','
```

Change [0] to another number, if your dataset returns more than one table.

Is the consuming system or application expecting a resultset?

Comment: Not able to export columns in csv where as columns now shows on Powershell window.For exporting colname in csv my code is`($DataSet.Tables[0].Columns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ColumnName) -join ',' | Export-Csv -path "E:\Users\neerajd\Documents\tethystrader-public-dev-general\src\SQL\Misc\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation`